# Show html images only when the item is being displayed

Tags: html

I saw this on Hulu.com once, but can't get it to behave that way.

The problem is that I have a "marquee" that slides when you click the next button. There are 2 images per section, a total of about 40 sections.

The issue is that the browser loads all 40 * 2 images and it is consuming bandwidth like crazy.

Is there a way to, saw load the images when the "slide" is shown?

Answer (score 0):

Load them in ajax. Look up [jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) for that, it's the simplest way.

It also look like you're doing a carousel. Maybe you could use [one of the many existing solutions](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) that already handle assynchronous loading of data.